# Angular 15 Font Awesome do not render

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome

I tried find some fresh information about the error I have but no results.
Here is my issue. I have a project in Angular 15.1.0, want to add some Font Awesome ikons, so following the steps:
`npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.12.x`
in the next step in `angular.json` I added `"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"` inside `"styles"` array on the first place. In the next step inside my component as a button value added `<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>`, but for some reasons spinner button do not render. In console I can see `<i>` element with font awesome classes, but there are no classes definition at all. I tried also import FA inside app.module.ts but same story. Does anyone has any idea where to find the issue? P.S For sure none of other styles covers those FA. In my project default style file are .SCSS if that's matter.

Answer (score 0):

to use angular-fontawesome you have to

0. install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons => `npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons --save`
1. import `FontAwesomeModule` in your used module
   for sample in main AppModule

   ```
   @NgModule({
     imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FontAwesomeModule
    ],
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
2. import the needed icon in your component

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { faSpinner } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html'
   })
   export class AppComponent {
     faSpinner = faSpinner;
   }
   ```
3. used it in your template by using tag `fa-icon` tag

`<fa-icon [icon]="faSpinner" [spin]="true"></fa-icon>`

you can found here a running sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xvlcfq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: ```import { faSpin } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';``` this path do not exist and any other one that can import faSpin

Comment: it's because it's fa-spinner the icon i update my reply in consequencies

Comment: and one last point don't forget to put `[spin]="true"` as attribute of your fa-icon

Comment: still same issue, path ```@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons``` do not exist after installing FA using npm

Comment: Only paths exist under @fortawesome are: angular-fontawesome, fontawesome-common-types, fontawesome-free, fontawesome-svg-core

Comment: here a running sample of the icon you need https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xvlcfq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: i found the difference you have also to install `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` by npm i edit the reply in consequencies